# Set muliptle classpath in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, eclipse-classpath

In my company, we are developing a Java based application which contains various plugins and in that I am working on a single plugin. The plugin that I am working on depends on many other plugins in the application. Suppose I am working on the application with installation 9, the jars are versioned with 9 and if I am working on installation 10 it is versioned as 10. So I need to set the classpath in my project for both 9 and 10 versioned jars in different paths.

I have a problem with the classpath and I am wondering how to set multiple classpath for a plugin project in eclipse.?

I have searched in the internet but could not find a proper document to set the mulitple classpath.

It would be great if someone gives an idea about this.

Comment: What do you mean by 'multiple classpath'?

Comment: In my company, we are developing a Java based application which contains various plugins and in that I am working on a single plugin. The plugin that I am working on depends on many other plugins in the application. Suppose I am working on the application with installation 9, the jars are versioned with 9 and if I am working on installation 10 it is versioned as 10. So I need to set the classpath in my project for both 9 and 10 versioned jars in different paths.

Comment: @Acjb, these details should be added to the question (not in a comment); without this information the question doesn't make sense. I suggest you edit the question to include the details and then delete the comment.

Answer (score 0):

The way you would typically do that (work on different versions of the same project) is by using branches in your SCM system (SVN, git, cvs, etc). An Eclipse project only has a single build classpath, and you would definitely not want to have multiple versions of the same dependency on the build path at the same time.